# Unable to locate a input element in iframe for selenium

Tags: jquery, html, selenium, iframe, selenium-webdriver

I am working on a selenium project, where I am trying to locate date text field and clear the text field. The field is inside a `iframe` tag where we have define the `iframe` tag as below

```
<iframe class='xyzframeclassname' src="http://thesrclink.com" ></iframe>
```

and the src consist the below input element creationDate which i need to input data. Below is the snippet of the src file

```
<td>
<span class="xyz">
<input id="creationDate" type="text" value="01/01/2000">
<input type="hidden" value="01/01/1900" name="startDate">
<input type="hidden" value="22/03/2017" name="endDate">
<span class="hint">
<a href="#">
<img onclick=some calendar related info>
</a> 
</span>
</span>  
</td>
```

I have used the below code

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("xyzframeclassname"));
driver.switchTo().frame(element);
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id="creationDate"]")).sendKeys("123");
```

Need the help where I am missing the thing. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @KishanPatel sorry my apolozies it is class not classname

Comment: Try finding iframe by following xpath: `//iframe[@class="xyzframeclassname"]`

Comment: `input` located inside an `iframe`? It's not clear from your `HTML` sample. Also share exception log

Comment: 1. Can you share the url incase it is public? 2. Share more of the HTML DOM.

Comment: @Andersson, yes the input is inside the iframe. there is no element is found exception is thrown

Comment: @Dev The url is intranet which is not access by outside the firewall, and i have this much code only... :(

Comment: `iframe` `WebElement` is called `element`, but you're trying to switch to `frameElement`... Is it typo?

Comment: @Andersson i am sorry, it is a typo error...

Comment: Ok. Are you sure that there is only one `iframe` on page with class name `'xyzframeclassname'`? Maybe you're switching to wrong `iframe`?

Comment: the page contain only one frame and it name is 'xyzframeclassname'

Answer (score 1):

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("xyzframeclassname"));
driver.switchTo().frame(frameElement);
driver.switchTo().activeElement()
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@id='creationDate']")
```

Try this...

Comment: Finally driver.switchTo().defaultContent()

Comment: You can add your code line by yourself, by click on the edit link underneath your post

Comment: it didnt worked as i am using, one container where the data is there... so i have created a separated question for it

Answer (score 1):

Try this once, it seems you have given wrong value while switching to frame

```
WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.xpath(@class='xyzframeclassname'));
driver.switchTo().frame(element);
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='creationDate']")).sendKeys("01/01/2000");
```

Comment: it didnt worked as i am using, one container where the data is there... so i have created a separated question for it.

Comment: Didn't got. Is above code not working for you? what error message you are getting? Or if you have created separate question then please provide the link in comment here.